# Speed up pandas iterrows calculation of seasons

Tags: python, pandas

```
isSpring = False

# Calculate season e.g. spring wheat season is only ~ May - August
if isSpring:
    # Change from name of month to a number e.g. January is 1, December is 12
    idx_srt_mon = strptime('May', '%B').tm_mon
    idx_end_mon = strptime('September', '%B').tm_mon
else:
    idx_srt_mon = strptime('September', '%B').tm_mon
    idx_end_mon = strptime('August', '%B').tm_mon

# Assign seasons, works for crops with season within 1 year and also winter crops with seasons spanning years
df['Season'] = numpy.nan
first_yr     = df.YEAR.unique()[0]
for i,  row in df.iterrows():
    cur_month = row.MONTH
    cur_yr    = row.YEAR

    if cur_month < idx_srt_mon:
        if not isSpring and (cur_month < idx_end_mon):
            if cur_yr > first_yr:
                df.set_value(i, 'Season', cur_yr - 1)
    else:
        if cur_month <= idx_end_mon or not isSpring:
            df.set_value(i, 'Season', cur_yr)
```

In the dataframe available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwyim6kc83mw3yf/df.csv?dl=0, I would like to add a new column which assigns a 'season' as follows:

1. If isSpring is TRUE, then assign the current year as season to all rows from idx_srt_mon to idx_end_mon (May to September)
2. If isSpring is FALSE, then the season starts in September of current year and goes upto August of next year. For this entire period, spanning across 2 years, the season is the year in which it started. E.g, if the start is September 2000, then the season will be 2000 from September 2000 to August 2001.
3. For all other cases, season is numpy.nan

I have used df.iterrows to do this computation, but it is very slow. How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to double check the logic, but this can be vectorized by building up the right boolean criteria, as below.

```
In [20]: first_yr = df.YEAR.min()

In [21]: if isSpring:
    ...:     df.loc[df['MONTH'] <= 9, 'Season'] = df.YEAR
    ...: else:
    ...:     df['Season'] = np.where(
                 (df['MONTH'] < 8) & (df['YEAR'] > first_yr), 
                     df['YEAR'] - 1, 
                     np.where(df['MONTH'] <= 8, df['YEAR'], 
                                                np.nan))
```

Comment: great, ty. never using iterrows again!